# can we extends org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler class and use this subclass as custom-handler

Tags: logging, jboss7.x

can we extends org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicRotatingFileHandler class and use this subclass as custom-handler, so that we can override suffix from ".yyyy-MM-dd-HH" to ".yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm" at runtime based on certain condition so that able to rotate log file every 10 minutes.

Eagarly waiting for solution.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the only requirement for a `custom-handler` is that it extends `java.util.logging.Handler`.

Depending on your requirements you may want to look at the [`org.jboss.logmanager.handlers.PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler`](https://github.com/jboss-logging/jboss-logmanager/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/logmanager/handlers/PeriodicSizeRotatingFileHandler.java). It's not in JBoss AS 7, but it is in WildFly and later versions of JBoss EAP 6.

Comment: Hi James, Thanks for your input.

Comment: can custom-handler which extends java.util.logging.Handler able to rotate log file without extending PeriodicRotatingFileHandler (available in jboss 7), because suffix attribute is available for this handler only which is responsible for rotating the log file and permissible suffix value is only those which is parsed by SimpleDateFormat class

Comment: Well you can extend a `PeriodicRotatingFileHandler` for a `custom-handler` if that's what you're looking to do.